# How to embed Webkit/Gecko layout engine and start using it for UI?

Tags: c++, webkit, gecko

I dont have much experience with C++ projects like Gecko or Webkit and I'd like to embed either Gecko or Webkit to a project so that I could construct my UI with HTML and CSS.

Something I'm wondering is that how do I handle events and such in C++ (no JavaScript)? If there's any resourceful tutorial on this topic I'd love to read it.

Answer (score 0):

Qt has a very nice module called QtWebkit that is good for this:

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtwebkit.html

You can evaluate Javascript in the webpage from within C++, and pass data from the webpage to your containing C++ program.

Not much use if you're already using something other than Qt, though ;) Maybe a little more info on what you've already done and what you're aiming for?

Comment: I really do not want the entire Qt framework. I need something simpler, just a way for me to embed Webkit/Gecko and use it for UI purposes.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [WebkitGTK](https://live.gnome.org/WebKitGtk/) which does pretty much the same as qtwebkit. The difference is that GTK is much lighter than QT. It has been ported to mac, linux and windows.

For iOS, there is the native [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

For Android, you can use [android.webkit.WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

Or, you can use [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) for a nice wrapper for mobile devices only.